# Only load div iframe onclick

Tags: html, iframe

I have this part of code. When the page is loaded also all div's are loaded but not yet visible. Is the an way to start loading the content of the div when it's clicked? Now the page is slowed down because of all div's

```
<a href="#?w=550" rel="popup_add_dossier" class="poplight" title="'.$lang['form_add'].'"><img src="images/icon/new.png" ></a>

<div id="popup_add_dossier" class="popup_block">
<iframe src="add_dossier.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="550" height="400">
```

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX technique to dynamically load content in a div upon a specific DOM Event instead of iframe?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php` when it only involves JavaScript and HTML?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you mean load the iframe inside the div only when an element is clicked? If so you can delete the iframe src attribute from the iframe tag and set the src only when the element is clicked.

On the iframe:

```
<iframe id='ifr' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="550" height="400">
```

On the clickable element:

```
onClick='document.getElementById("ifr").src="add_dossier.php";'
```

Comment: Great soltion altough I can't get it to work with adding the onclick to the image <img src="images/icon/new.png" onClick="document.getElementById("ifr").src="add_dossier.php";" > The div is shown but empty.

Comment: Have you added the id on the iframe? Look at the javascript console if it throws some errors

Comment: Yes, I have. The error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } This is the complete line: echo '<td><a href="#?w=700" rel="popup_add_relatie" class="poplight" title="'.$lang['form_add'].'"><img src="images/icon/new.png" onClick="document.getElementById("ifr").src="add_relatie.php";" ></a></td>';

Comment: You are using doblue quotes inside a double quoted attribute. The onClick must be followed by single quotes. This is the correct code:
echo '<td><a href="#?w=700" rel="popup_add_relatie" class="poplight" title="'.$lang['form_add'].'"><img src="images/icon/new.png" onClick=\'document.getElementById("ifr").src="add_relatie.php";\' ></a></td>';

Answer (score 5):

jQuery makes it easy!

Load below in the `<head>` section.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    $("iframe").each(function(){
        this.tmp = this.src;
        this.src = "";
    })
    .parent(".popup_block")
    .click(function(){
        var frame = $(this).children("iframe")[0];
        console.log(frame);        frame.src = frame.tmp;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if(!$('#iframe').length) {
                $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="http://google.com" width="700" height="450"></iframe>');
        }
    });   
});
</script>

<a id="button">Button</a>
<div id="iframeHolder"></div>
```

Comment: how do we pass src dynamically from <a src> to javascript code.