# Java class gets loaded even if iframe is not called by clicking the link. Why?

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I came across a strange problem . I have a jsp , which is calling an iframe . The iframe gets loaded with data from java.

Now to render the iframe i am using customized  [control-modal.js](http://code.google.com/p/infoscoop/source/browse/trunk/src/main/web/js/lib/control.modal.js?r=370).

Now  my iframe is coded after li tag like this :

```
<li>
<a id="modalLink"  href="#myModal">Set up my Modal</a>
</li>
<div id="myModal" >
<div class="modalsubcol">
<p class="close"><a href="#"><img src="/.../close-button.gif" alt="Close"/></a></p>
<iframe id="modal-frame"style="display:none;" height="430" 
width="675" src="<%= getTheModal()%>"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

And i call the modal in the head part of my jsp like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function modalOverride(){
var myModal;
$('modal-frame').style.display ='block';
myModal = new Control.Modal($('modalLink'), {
afterOpen : function(){$$('.close a').invoke('observe','click',function(e){Control.Modal.close(); Event.stop(e);});},
opacity: 0.3,
width: 675,
fade: true,
fadeDuration: 0.1,
autoOpenIfLinked: false
});
}
</script>
```

Now the link : **Set up my Modal** is part of a page containing many links. When i bring that page up, the java class that renders the data fro the modal also gets called. But this must happen only when , i click on the **Set up my Modal** link.

Before some one tells me , this issue is not due to

```
  window.onload
```

event, i have used it as otherwise the modal does not get loaded when i click the a fore mentioned link. I have tried by removing the **window.onload** event as well. If i do that, the java class still gets loaded and now my iframe does not get loaded . No errors come up in fire bug as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop this on the page:

```
<iframe id="modal-frame"style="display:none;" height="430" width="675" src="<%= getTheModal()%>"></iframe>
```

The source of the iframe is loaded regardless pf whether you have the display: none css property set.

Also note, JSPs do not "call" iframes, they simply render an iframe tag in the HTTP response, the browsers than interprets the iframes and renders the iframe src

If you wish to show/hide the iframe you can do so with JQuery:

```
$('.modal-frame').toggle();
```

If you truly wish to only include the other page when you click a link, you need to use AJAX to make a request when the link is clicked or load an iframe dynamically with Javascript.

Comment: So what do i do ? How do i at least stop the java class from getting loaded without clicking on the link ?

Comment: The standard way to do this is using an AJAX request: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you may also be able to load an iframe dynamically on clicking.

Comment: Can you share some info/Urls which shows how to load iframe strictly on clicking either via Ajax or javascript.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015809/only-load-div-iframe-onclick