# Load iFrame On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have 20 iframes on one page and I am trying to prevent all of them loading at once. The iframes are generated by a shortcode, so it's not as easy as inputting the source URL onclick. Is there a way to do this once the iframe code has already been generated.

When #file-1 is clicked, I wanted to load the iframe in the wrapper #file-1-p

```
<h4 id="file-1" class="click files shadow">Seven Habits Profile</h4>
<section id="file-1-p" class="popup white big-shadow">
    <div class="popup-wrapper">
        <div class="ex purple shadow">
            <div>
                <span class="f-white">X</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ead-preview"><div class="ead-document" style="position:relative;padding-top:90%;"><iframe src="//docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyourroundtable.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F7_Habits_Profile.pdf&amp;embedded=true&amp;hl=en" title="Embedded Document" style="width:100%; height:100%; border: none; position: absolute;left:0;top:0;"></iframe></div><p class="embed_download"><a href="http://yourroundtable.com/wp-content/uploads/7_Habits_Profile.pdf" download="">Download [49.83 KB] </a></p></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only load div iframe onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015809/only-load-div-iframe-onclick)

Comment: Not a duplicate because I am trying to load on click without inputting src with jquery or javascript.